# Adding field to Angular Firestore Collection from Mat Dialog

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular-material, dialog

I have a main component that opens a Dialog. In the Dialog I have a form with a textarea and a save button. Now the main component has a user id which is passed to the dialog. So when the form is saved, the data in text area along with the ID passed should be saved in the collection. I can save the text area data but somehow not able to create the field for ID and save its value.
So in the collection 2 fields are - ID and Details. In the dialog component I have the following to as instance of form.

```
this.userForm = new FormGroup({
    'details' : new FormControl(),
  })   
 onSubmit() { 
    this.clientService.addDetails(this.data ,this.userForm.value);      
  }
```

Service-

```
addDetails(id:string, details: User) {
  this.db.collection('Details')
  .add(details)
  .then(res => {
    console.log('Details added Successfully');
  })   
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error' ,error);
  });}
```

HTML-

```
<form [formGroup]="userForm"  (ngSubmit)= "onSubmit()" >
            <mat-form-field >
                <mat-label></mat-label>
                <textarea matInput matInputid="details" name="details" formControlName="details" ></textarea>
            </mat-form-field>
            <div>
                <button  type="submit" mat-raised-button color="primary" >Save</button>
                <button  type="button" mat-raised-button color="primary"  >Cancel</button>
              </div>
            
        </form>
```

Comment: I don't think that your question is quite clear enough. Could you elaborate on exactly the struggle you are experiencing?

Comment: Can you debug and confirm that addDetails is correctly called. It may happen, with a button of type "submit" that the form is submitted before the Firebase method is triggered.